# Getting the value of a variable from another function

Tags: python, function, variables

I am unable to get the answer variable from the question function to check if the answer is indeed correct.

Following is what I have done so far:

```
import random
import operator
a = 0
ops = {
    '+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub
}
def generateQuestion():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    a = ops.get(op)(x,y)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(x, op, y))
    return a

def askQuestion():
    guess = input("")
    if guess == a:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong, the answer is ", a)


generateQuestion()
askQuestion()
```

I cut out the in between stuff which is all working fine.

I'm aware I've set a = 0 at the top as well otherwise I got a ***was not defined*** error. However, I can't get the math from outside of the generateQuestion().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alleviate the need for the global by passing the answer value straight into `askQuestion`.

Don't forget to convert the return from `input` to an int, if you are running python 3. If using python 2 then you would not require the `int` conversion.

```
import random
import operator

ops = {
    '+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub
}

def generateQuestion():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    a = ops.get(op)(x,y)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(x, op, y))
    return a

def askQuestion(a):
    guess = input("")

    try:
        if int(guess) == a:
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("Wrong, the answer is ", a)
    except:
        print('Did not input integer')

askQuestion(generateQuestion())
```

Comment: In Python 2 `input` parses any literals you enter, so if you enter `3` you'll get an int, no casting required.

Comment: Given that the OP is using `print` function (and no import from `__future__`) I have assumed Python 3.

Comment: Yea python 3.4, first time using python, I usually do my projects in unity script, thanks for your answer as well

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
import operator

ops = {
    '+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub
}

def generateQuestion():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    a = ops.get(op)(x,y)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(x, op, y))
    return a

def askQuestion(a):
    guess = input("")
    if guess == a:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong, the answer is ", a)

variable = generateQuestion()
askQuestion(variable)
```

Comment: An explanation of why this works would be good. Also, the initial assignment of `a = 0` isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting use to python, a now gives the right answer, but regardless of what input I enter it gives "wrong answer"

Answer (score 0):

You have a *scoping* issue. Your variable `a` inside `generateQuestion` is **not the same variable** as `a` outside.

In order to fix this, you need to declare `a` as global inside `generateQuestion`.

```
import random
import operator
a = 0
ops = {
    '+':operator.add,
    '-':operator.sub
}
def generateQuestion():
    x = random.randint(1, 10)
    y = random.randint(1, 10)
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    global a
    a = ops.get(op)(x,y)
    print("What is {} {} {}?\n".format(x, op, y))
    return a

def askQuestion():
    guess = input("")
    if guess == a:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong, the answer is ", a)


generateQuestion()
askQuestion()
```

Hav a look at this:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/scope_resolution_legb_rule.ipynb